# Is there a more ruby idiomatic way to remove creation of configurable object dependencies?

Tags: ruby, oop, dependency-injection

I am trying to clean up some old code, remove dependencies, and make it more testable.

When I find situations like the following, where a parameterized object is being created in a method. For example in this code:

```
class Bar
  def initialize parameter
    @parameter = parameter
  end
end

class Foo
  def initialize some_parameter
    @some_parameter = some_parameter
  end
  def some_method
    ...
    ...
    bar = Bar.new parameter  ## here is the dependency I would like to remove
    ...
  end
end
```

I have been creating a factory class and injecting it into the constructor and then using that to create the instance, as shown here:

```
class Bar
  def initialize parameter
    @parameter = parameter
  end
end

class BarFactory
  def create parameter 
    Bar.new parameter
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_reader :bar_factory
  def initialize some_parameter, bar_factory: nil
    @bar_factory = bar_factory || BarFactory.new  
    @some_parameter = some_parameter
  end
  def some_method
    ...
    ...
    bar = bar_factory.create parameter
    ...
  end
end
```

I think this is an improvement, in that I can inject a different factory for test, or inject a different factory in the future if needed.  But since I find myself doing this more often, I am wondering if I am falling into some anti-pattern, or if there is a more ruby idiomatic way to do the same thing?

Most of the research I did on this generally turns up injecting dependencies into a constructor, which is what I am doing here, but in this case I am injecting a factory rather than a simple object.

Comment: How about calling the `Bar` factory elsewhere then initializing `Foo` with a `Bar` instance, storing it as an instance variable? Removes the necessity to call the factory inside your instance method. If your instance method needs to use the factory dynamically, what you're doing here makes sense although with the code you've shown it doesn't seem necessary to use a factory at all, since there's not much logic changed from the `Foo` initializer.

Comment: Maybe I did not make it clear enough, but the bar created inside the method,  needs input from the method.  So for example the parameter passed to the create method of the bar_factory in some_method is generated by some_method.  If this were not the case, I would have done as you suggest and pass a bar into the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not seeing any benefit of having a dedicated factory class in Ruby, i.e. it smells of Java-style patterns (working around the fact that classes are not first-class objects there). Why wouldn't you simply:

```
class Bar
  def initialize parameter
    @parameter = parameter
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_reader :barlike_class
  def initialize some_parameter, barlike_class: Bar
    @barlike_class = barlike_class  
    @some_parameter = some_parameter
  end
  def some_method
    ...
    ...
    bar = barlike_class.new parameter
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree, it does smell like java, which is partly why I asked the question, I think what you show here will work nicely.  Let me play with it a bit first before I check it off.

Comment: I guess it's really just the normal constructor dependency injection, but as you say, in ruby classes are objects as well, so no reason they should be treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

What about depending on a role instead of a concrete class, so you can change the object composition (the objects graph) at runtime.
Maybe something like :

```rb
class DefaultBar
  def initialize params
    @params = params
  end

  def do_that
  end
end

class AdvancedBar
  def initialize params
    @params = params
  end

  def do_that
  end
end

class Foo
  def self.default params
    new params, bareable: DefaultBar.new params
  end

  def self.advanced params
    new params, bareable: AdvancedBar.new params
  end

  def initialize params, bareable:
    @bareable = bareable  
    @params   = params
  end

  def do_this
    @bareable.do_that
  end
end

# it can be used like
Foo.default.do_this
Foo.advanced.do_this
```

Here the factories are implemented with class methods, and allow to build the different object graphs.
You can even inject the dependency (a mock for example) at construction time if you need it.